# Sampling from gaussian distribution

Tags: python, pytorch, sampling, normal-distribution

My question is very specific. Given a `k` dimensional Gaussian distribution with mean and standard deviation, say I wish to sample `10` points from this distribution. But the `10` samples should be very different from each other. For example, I do not wish to sample `5` of those very close to the mean (By very close, we may assume for this example within `1` sigma) which may happen if I do random sampling. Let us also add an additional constraint that all the drawn samples should be at least 1 sigma away from each other. Is there a known way to sample in this fashion methodically? Is there any such module in PyTorch which can do so?

Sorry if this thought is ill posed but I am trying to understand if such a thing is possible.

Comment: So you want to generate a gaussian distribution, select `n` samples from it, but each sample should be at least 1 sigma from each other?

Comment: @wundermahn Yes, I just updated the question to ask if there exists a module in Python to do so efficiently?

Comment: why not use [`torch.normal()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.normal.html) with different `mean` and `std` for each of the `n` samples you need, and then stack all the samples in a single tensor? Another idea would be to *oversample* and throw away the samples that don't fit your constraint.

Comment: @kmario23 See my comment to the answer below regarding **oversampling**. I explain there why I think such approach is computationally prohibitive. Regarding using different `mean` and `std`, unfortunately that is not an option for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no such library. The problem you are trying to solve is straightforward. Just check if the random number you get is 'far enough' from the mean. The complexity of that check is constant. The probability of a point **not** to be between one sigma from the mean is ~32%. It is not that unlikely.

Comment: Yes, that is a fair thought. But allow me to pose a different question. How about if I want all my samples to be at least `1` sigma away from every other sample? Then as the desired number of samples increase, then one may need to sample many many more random numbers and it can be computationally prohibitive, wouldn't it?

Comment: Agreed, that is a definitely more interesting question. One whose complexity can't decide from the top of my head. It's it going to take longer? Definitely.